# adding styles a word using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to replace a Word using JavaScript, but when the script runs this one replace the Word in the JavaScript too.
The idea is add somes style a Word when the script find the Word on document, then i use **REPLACE** to do this, look the code

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('Amaru', '<span style=font-family:"Inder"!important;color:#0c5d4e;text-transform:lowercase;>amaru</span>');
```

Thanks you so much.

Comment: Is moving the script tag out of the body a possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a syntax error as well. Because you didn't wrap your style in the quotations.

However, it's better to use Regex.

```js
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Amaru/g, '<span style=\'font-family:"Inder"!important;color:#0c5d4e;text-transform:lowercase;\'>amaru</span>');
```

```html
Amaru 1
<br>
Amaru 2
```

Comment: great, its Works. but now have another problema also replace the **links** or **ALT** where say Amaru

Comment: @sittelle, please open another post. And, this time, put more clear codes. More codes leads you the result faster

Comment: How is this even an answer? It doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: @tjscience it solve the problema, but i forget explain also replace links and ALT, that means was my fail.

Comment: How does this solve the problem that you originally posted about the 'replace' method replacing the words in the script? This answer does not address that issue.

Comment: @tjscience to be exacly, that idea was replace a Word for the same Word but adding styles.

Comment: @tjscience, The fact is, sometimes someone can't ask a clear question but it doesn't mean s/he does not have problem. I could find out what Sittelle wants and did for him/her. Thanks for your attention and I'm sure Sittelle will revise the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

The best way to approach this may be to wrap the content that you want to run the replace on in a parent div. That way you do not have to worry about the replace affecting anything other than what is in the content div.

Also, if you want to replace more than just the first match, you will have to use a regex literal (/Amari/gi) as shown in the snippet below. The i ignores case.

```html
<div id="replace-content">
  Amari
</div>
<script>
  var amari = 'Amari';
  
  var replaceContent = document.getElementById('replace-content');
  var html = replaceContent.innerHTML.replace(/Amari/gi, '<span style="color:red">Amari</span>');
  replaceContent.innerHTML = html;
  
  console.log(amari);
</script>
```

**EDIT**

If you are not able to modify the markup as Rob pointed out in his comment, you can choose to omit the script tag from your DOM query.

```html
    <div>
      Amari
    </div>
    <script>
      var amari = 'Amari';
      
      var elements = document.querySelectorAll('*:not(script)');
      
      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var html = elements[i].innerHTML.replace(/Amari/gi, '<span style="color:red">Amari</span>');
        elements[i].innerHTML = html;
      }
      console.log(amari);
    </script>
```

Comment: Whilst this is a good idea, however you're assuming that the OP can alter the markup outside of JavaScript. Which they haven't indicated.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a Regular expression as you don't want the replace to match strings that are within a script tag, this makes it a little more complicated.

However you can accomplish this with a regex technique called a [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

A regex like this should do the trick:

`(?!<script[^>]*?>)(\bAmaru\b)(?![^<]*?<\/script>)`

Here in place with your code:

```
var regex = /(?!<script[^>]*?>)(\bAmaru\b)(?![^<]*?<\/script>)/;
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(regex, '<span style=font-family:"Inder"!important;color:#0c5d4e;text-transform:lowercase;>amaru</span>');
```

*TBH I wouldn't really recommend using regex on raw HTML*

Comment: this has a problema, look the Word `</script>` is closing the first `/`

Comment: @sittelle my apologies, I've fixed that.

Comment: thanks, you know how can avoid take links and alt, where the Word appears?, thanks you so much.

Comment: @sittelle You've already accepted an answer here, why have you accepted an answer that doesn't solve your problem?